# How am I misusing EvenQ, or, how are EvenQ and (Mod[2,#]==0)& differently evaluated?

Tags: expression-test

While working on a problem, I was using `EvenQ` in a `RegionPlot`.  I came across this interesting case (simplified here for specificity).  I expected to see a bunch of stripes, but got nothing:

```
RegionPlot[EvenQ[Floor[x]],{x,0,10},{y,0,10}]
```

[image: A blank plot with axes, but no data]

However, it was fine if I used `Mod` to the same effect instead:

```
RegionPlot[Mod[Floor[x],2]==0,{x,0,10},{y,0,10}]
```

[image: A plot showing five vertical stripes, spaced unit width apart]

I also get the correct results if I substitute `(Mod[Floor[#],2]==0&)` for `EvenQ`.  I also tried a version with `Assert[Head[#]==Integer]&` included appropriately, and it did not ever raise an error, but the Mathematica evaluation model is still a bit mystical to me in some bits.

Comment: EvenQ[Floor[x]] evaluates to False. Your other examples don't evaluate, so they work when a value is substituted for x.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In version 10.1.0 under Windows:

```
RegionPlot[EvenQ[Floor[x]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

However as Carl Woll [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139281/how-am-i-misusing-evenq-or-how-are-evenq-and-mod2-0-differently-evalua#comment376015_139281) `EvenQ` evaluates to `False` when its argument is symbolic.  As a rule `*Q` functions return `True` or `False` at the time of evaluation; they do not remain in an unevaluated form waiting for the argument to be of the right type.

Presumably in the version of *Mathematica* you are using [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) attempts a symbolic evaluation and therefore fails on `EvenQ`.

If you prefer the delayed behavior you can use a mediating function with `_?NumericQ`:

```
even[n_?NumericQ] := EvenQ[n]

even[x] /. x -> 4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Or, theoretically, `Evaluated -> False` may prevent symbolic evaluation:

```
RegionPlot[EvenQ[Floor[x]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> False]
```

Comment: It seems the change with `RegionPlot` is made in version 11, but at least the traditional `Plot` family is the same as before.