# Valid predicates for Probability[]?

Tags: evaluation, probability-or-statistics

I don't understand what counts as a valid predicate to Probability[].

This does not work:

```
Probability[EvenQ@x, x \[Distributed] Range@10]

(*  0  *)
```

According to the docs, this should be equivalent to

```
Sum[Boole@EvenQ@x, {x, Range@6}]/Length@Range@6

(*  1/2  *)
```

which does give the expected answer.  This also works,

```
Probability[Mod[x, 2] == 0, x \[Distributed] Range@6]

(*  1/2  *)
```

As does this, when the output is subsequently evaluated:

```
Probability[Defer@EvenQ@x, x \[Distributed] Range@6]

(*  1/6 (Boole[EvenQ[1]] + Boole[EvenQ[2]] + Boole[EvenQ[3]] + 
    Boole[EvenQ[4]] + Boole[EvenQ[5]] + Boole[EvenQ[6]])  *)
```

I hesitate to blame the tool, but when the explicitly stated equivalent formulation gives a different answer, it sure looks like it's not confusion on my part.  Is it me?  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it is the way `EvenQ` works.  From the documentation on `EvenQ`:  `EvenQ[expr]` returns `False` unless `expr` is manifestly an even integer (i.e. has head Integer, and is even).  Without the `Defer` it immediately returns `False` inside the `Probability` function.

Comment: The use of the term "manifestly" in the documentation of a function (`EvenQ`, `IntegerQ`, etc.) is what you need to watch out for.  In those cases you'd need to use `Defer`.

Comment: Something like that was the only thing I could think of, but it was puzzling why `EvenQ` and `Equal` (in `Mod[x,2]==0`) would work differently.  But that doesn't explain what the documentation for `Probability` says: "For a dataset _data_, the probability of _pred_ is given by `Sum[Boole[pred],{x,data}]/Length[data]`"; that code gives the right answer so it must only be 'notionally given by' it.

Comment: `Trace` is enlightening.  For the `Probability` version, the first thing that happens is that `EvenQ[x]` is evaluated and, per Jim's observation gives `False`, whereas, for the `Sum` version, `EvenQ` is only evaluated after `x` is replaced with an integer.

Comment: Related: [(139281)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139281/764).

Comment: @JimBaldwin `Defer` is meant only for formatting. It is absolutely not meant for evaluation control.  Never try to use it for *programming*, and controlling program flow.  It does not even do anything useful without a notebook interface.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Thanks. And great answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different perspective to complement gwr's answer:

Mathematica has functions for traditional programming, and functions which represent Mathematical concepts and are suitable for symbolic computation.  The line between the two is somewhat blurred.  This is good for keeping things simple, but it can also be confusing.  A stricter [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) would make this distinction explicit at the cost of some convenience, and would provide separate tools for these two types of uses.

"Programming functions" will evaluate immediately, just as they do in other languages.  `EvenQ` is such a function.  Generally, functions ending in `Q` will evaluate immediately to either `True` or `False`.  Example:

```
EvenQ /@ {0, 1, x}
(* {True, False, False} *)
```

Thus it is better to think of `EvenQ[x]` as "`x` is of `Integer` datatype and is even".  It will return `False` for anything that is not of the `Integer` *datatype*, which is not the same thing as an *integer in the mathematical* sense.  E.g., `EvenQ[2.0]` is `False` because `2.0` is `Real`.  $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a mathematical concept, datatypes are a programming concept.

"Mathematical functions" do not evaluate with symbolic values and can be used to represent mathematical statements. `Positive` is such a function. Note that even though it returns `True` or `False`, it does not have `Q` in the name.  Example:

```
Positive /@ {0, 1, x}
(* {False, True, Positive[x]} *)
```

It can be used to represent a Mathematica statement, on which we can perform operations:

```
FullSimplify[Positive[x^2], Element[x, Reals] && x != 0]
(* True *)
```

An example of a function that blurs the line between math and programming is `If`.  If its first argument is neither `True` nor `False`, then it does not evaluate, and can be used as a sort of substitute for [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html). Note though that it has a fourth argument: when specified, [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) will evaluate immediately.

In general, you can think of programming function as "code" that is meant to run. You can think of mathematical functions as data that can be operated on.  `Probability` is meant to be used with mathematical functions—anything else will evaluate *before* `Probability` even has a chance to see it. That excludes anything that has a `Q` in the name.

---

A note about [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html): this is a function that is meant purely for *displaying*/*formatting* things in notebooks.  It is *not* meant for evaluation control.

Answer (score 4):

The reasons the supposedly *false* behavior of `EvenQ` have been explained nicely in [(139281)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139281/764). Basically there are three solutions:

**1) Avoid predicates which will work on symbolic inputs**

Next to using `Mod[ x, 2] == 0` there is a more compact form available:

```
Probability[ x ~ Divisible ~ 2, x \[Distributed] Range @ 10 ]
```

> 1/2

**2) Modify the predicates so they will not work on symbolic inputs**

This is the solution given in the thread that I have linked. For completeness:

```
nEvenQ[ x_?NumericQ ] := EvenQ @ x

Probability[ nEvenQ @ x, x \[Distributed] Range @ 10 ]
```

> 1/2

**3) Prevent the predicates from evaluating prematurely**

While in the OP [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) has been used already, a nicer solution (imo) exists using [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) and [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html):

```
Probability[ Inactivate @ EvenQ[x], x \[Distributed] Range @ 10 ]

(* 1/10 (Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][1]] + Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][2]] + 
Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][3]] + Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][4]] + 
Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][5]] + Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][6]] + 
Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][7]] + Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][8]] + 
Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][9]] + Boole[Inactive[EvenQ][10]]) *)

Activate @ %
```

> 1/2